# App crash when calling a method after a delay

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash, delay

I am trying to execute the doit() method in  OnCreate, waiting for 5 seconds to allow for the method's functionality to fully load and then call the tester() method within the wait function. 
The app functions properly without the delay and displays 'TextView' which is the output of the textbox before the function has finished, I would like to wait for 5 seconds until doit() has finished loading and then display the contents of texx from the tester() after the wait. Any help would be appreciated.
Images linked below is a crash output and the app working.

[Crash output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDKnp.png)

[App working without delay, but doesn't output textbox content because it hasn't loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfbt9.png)

```
public class AppHome extends AppCompatActivity implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
    TextView texx;
    private ArrayList<String> al;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    private int i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_home);

        new doit().execute();

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
           tester();
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
        public void tester() {
            texx = findViewById(R.id.text1);
            String text = texx.getText().toString();

            //String num = text;
            String[] str = text.split(",");
            final ArrayList al = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str));

            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item, R.id.helloText, al);

            SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer = findViewById(R.id.frame);


            registerForContextMenu(flingContainer);


            flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            flingContainer.setFlingListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {
                @Override
                public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {
                    // this is the simplest way to delete an object from the Adapter (/AdapterView)
                    Log.d("LIST", "removed object!");
                    al.remove(0);
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onLeftCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                    //Do something on the left!
                    //You also have access to the original object.
                    //If you want to use it just cast it (String) dataObject
                    Toast.makeText(AppHome.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onRightCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                    Toast.makeText(AppHome.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int itemsInAdapter) {
                    // Ask for more data here
                    al.add("XML ".concat(String.valueOf(i)));
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.d("LIST", "notified");
                    i++;
                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(float scrollProgressPercent) {
                }
            });

            // Optionally add an OnItemClickListener
        /*
        flingContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(int itemPosition, Object dataObject) {

            }
        });

         */

        }

        public class doit extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                String words = "";
                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://screenscrape4top40.000webhostapp.com/").get();
                    words = doc.text();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return words;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPostExecute(String words) {
                super.onPostExecute(words);
                texx.setText(words);

            }
        }


        public void showPopup (View v){
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
            popup.inflate(R.menu.dropdown_menu1);
            popup.show();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick (MenuItem item){
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.item1:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Item 1 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.item2:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Item 2 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.item3:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Item 3 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.item4:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Item 4 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are only setting the variable `texx` 5 seconds after. The thread is finishing before that , so `texx`  is null at that point.

Comment: Might I suggest two things, firstly move the AsyncTask outside into its own class file (or making the class static). You will end up leaking a `Context` otherwise. Additionally, [AsyncTask is official deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask). There are some better solutions for dealing with concurrency. Kotlin has Coroutines. Java and Kotlin have RxJava. As some examples.

Answer (score 2):

move following line in onCreate(), after setContentView() :

```
texx = findViewById(R.id.text1);
```

Comment: This is correct. Additionally a good solution would be to move the `tester()` call out of the handler and put it in onPostExecute. If the call takes 6 seconds, for whatever reason, the data won't be ready yet.